# Duplicate parent paths in url bar

Tags: react-router, history.js, relayjs

Using:

```
"react-router": "^2.0.0",
"react-router-relay": "^0.9.0",
```

When I push any link under a parent path, the parent path is duplicated in the URL bar once for every new `router.push` call.

```
// http://localhost:3000

router.push('auth/profile')
// http://localhost:3000/auth/profile

router.push('auth/profile')
// http://localhost:3000/auth/auth/profile

router.push('auth/browse')
// http://localhost:3000/auth/auth/auth/browse
```

When I log the `location` (from `react-router`), it does not show the duplicates. Maybe the browser is pushing the parent path onto the basename?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Changing

```
router.push('auth/profile')
```

to

```
router.push('/auth/profile')
```

fixed this.